# If the cross product result is known, then how to calculate the factors vector $A$ and vector $B\,$?

Tags: vector-analysis, nonlinear-system, cross-product, nonlinear-dynamics

Assume that
$$\nabla H_1\times\nabla H_2 \:=\: V\quad\text{and}\quad
V \:=\: \big(σy, x(r − z), xy\big)\,.$$
My question: If $V$ is given, is there any way to find out what $\,\nabla H_1\,$ and $\,\nabla H_2\,$ are?

The answer for the given $V$ should be
$$ V\:=\:\big(σy, x(r − z), xy\big) \;=\;\underbrace{(0, y, z − r)}_{\qquad =\,\nabla H_1}\:\times\:\underbrace{(−x, 0, σ)}_{\qquad =\,\nabla H_2}\,.
$$
From a mathematical point of view, it is impossible to solve since we have six variables and only three equations. But there is a paper in which it is mentioned that it can be decomposed. I am not getting any idea how this is possible.

I am attaching the link to the paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3881
and refer to equation $(3.17)$ in it.

Comment: You have six unknowns to attempt to solve for with three equations. I'm thinking you can't do this.

Comment: @SeanRoberson: Actually there are only *two* unknowns in the given equation $\nabla H_1 \times \nabla H_2 = V$, namely the functions $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of searching for the phrase “Clebsch–Monge potentials” (which they mention in the paper) revealed that it's a known but nontrivial fact that any (nice) divergence-free vector field in $\mathbf{R}^3$ can be written as the cross product of two gradients (at least locally, and away from points where the vector field is zero). I didn't find much material about this online, but there are proofs in some old vector analysis books (L. Brand, *Vector and Tensor Analysis*, §104, and R. Aris, *Vectors, Tensors, and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics*, §3.43), and also a proof of a more general result in $\mathbf{R}^n$ in the paper [Representation of divergence-free vector fields](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254190192_Representation_of_divergence-free_vector_fields) by C. Barbarosie.